# Group by according to the column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to average on columns after grouping them based on the the column names. An example dataframe is generated below.  All the column names having same string preceding `_` needs to be averaged together. The output will be a 10x3 column.

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
import numpy as np
df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 7)))
df.columns = ['9_0', '9_1', '99_0', '99_1', '99_2',  '999_0', '999_1']
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function to extract the common string and use it a key to group data column wise.

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).mean()
Out[903]: 
      9         99   999
0  52.0  50.333333  68.5
1  43.0  44.666667  47.0
2  20.0  62.666667  48.0
3  58.5  65.000000  77.5
4  46.0  64.000000  30.0
5  16.5  55.000000  57.5
6  51.5  48.333333  43.0
7  20.0  44.000000  35.5
8  57.5  11.666667  36.0
9  31.5  28.000000  49.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby columns (after `str.split`)

```
df.groupby(pd.Series(df.columns.values).str.split('_',expand=True)[0].values,axis=1).mean()
Out[472]: 
      9         99   999
0  41.0  30.666667  26.5
1  20.5  36.666667  11.0
2  49.5  27.333333  44.0
3  35.5  68.000000  75.5
4  37.5  21.000000  60.5
5  40.5  25.000000  15.0
6  62.5  73.666667  60.0
7  50.5  76.333333  51.0
8  46.5  37.333333  29.0
9  49.0  51.666667  80.5
```